# Unattended execution of C# scripts

Tags: development, powershell, sharepoint-server, batch, script

I'm a beginner designing automatizing tasks.
I have 2 scripts in C# .These scripts generate two XML docs which are connected and synchronized with two native lists in a SharePoint Portal through Layer2.

I tested this architecture-flow locally **from-in** my PC and it works but what I want to do is automatize the execution and fix a remote storage for this flow-scripts and the resultant XMLs files. I want to fix a "task" which execute and save hourly this scripts **in-from** a external path (not locally in my PC) in order to *keep updated* the info (XML docs) in SharePoint **without human intervention**.

I tried to find info but I still a bit lost. I don't know what platforms or resources let me do this :batch processing , Power Shell , VS Timer Tasks , Cloud like Sky Drive... Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you eventually set up your script. If you have developed a console application in VS you can let it run periodically using the Task Scheduler. For console apps you can point it out directly to the console application itself. If you have something written with PowerShell then point for the program to launch the PowerShell executable located under "\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" and pass the path to your script as a parameter.

A good explanation how to do it with PowerShell can be found here: [How to Shedule a PowerShell Script](http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/how-to-schedule-a-powershell-script/)

How to set up the Windows Task Scheduler: [Schedule a task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: But Task Scheduler means that the execution has to be locally , isn't it? I want to program a remote task/job to be executed hourly on a server or I'm not sure , but the execution of the scripts shouldn't be conditioned by the machine (PC) . It has to be independent.

Comment: Can't you create the task on the remote server to run independently?